# Program doesn't work without an initial value

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, swift

The program works fine with `var dig = 0` and it doesn't work with `var dig:Int` I get an error: `Variable "dig" used before being initialized` Could you explain me why?

```
func myFunc(a:Int, b:Int) {
    var c = a / b
    var o = a % b
    var v = 0
    var dig = 0
    if o != 0 {println("\(a)/\(b) = \(c) и \(o)/\(b)")}
    else {println("\(a)/\(b) = \(c)")}

    if a > b {
        v = b
    }
    else {
        v = a
    }
    for var i = 1; i <= v; ++i {
        if a % i == 0 && b % i == 0 {dig = i}
    }
    println("\(dig) -  greatest common denominator of \(a) and \(b)")
}

myFunc(27,81)
```

Comment: There is a path that your code can take where dig is never given a value, then you try to print it's value which is undefined.

Comment: How about `var dig:Int?`. I do often mix up ? and ! so it might be either one. Try them

Comment: The compiler is trying to protect you from a nasty, hard to detect bug - using a variable that hasn't yet been initialized.  These type of bugs can be nightmares to find as they often manifest themselves as "release only" as the debugger is better about clearing out memory, etc.

It's a best-practice in any language to always initialize a variable when declaring it, if it isn't initialized immediately afterward.  It is a very cheap operation can can save you a lot of grief.  And Swift is enforcing it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place you set the value of `dig` is inside of an `if` statement that is inside of a `for` loop.  The Swift compiler does not know if the body of the `for` loop will be executed, and it doesn't know if the `if` statement will ever be true, so it has to assume that there is a path in which `dig` is not initialized.

Consider this simpler example:

```
func myFunc(a:Int, b:Int) {
    var dig: Int

    if a >= b {
        dig = 3
    }

    if a < b {
        dig = 4
    }
    println("\(dig) -  greatest common denominator of \(a) and \(b)")
}
```

This example also gives the same error, because Swift considers each `if` separately.  It is obvious to us that a is either greater than or equal to b or it is less than b, but Swift doesn't go that far in evaluating the situation.  It just considers that each `if` may not be `true`, and `dig` is only set inside of `if`s, so it is possible (as far as Swift is concerned) that `dig` may not be set.

```
func myFunc(a:Int, b:Int) {
    var dig: Int

    if a >= b {
        dig = 3
    } else {
        dig = 4
    }
    println("\(dig) -  greatest common denominator of \(a) and \(b)")
}
```

If you change the second condition to an else, Swift is then happy because it can reason that the `if` must be `true` or `false` and `dig` is set in each path, so it will certainly have a value before the `println` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know mathematics good enough to
recognize that the statement

```
if a % i == 0 && b % i == 0 {dig = i}
```

is actually executed at least once (for `i == 1`). Therefore
the compiler assumes that `dig` might be undefined at

```
println("\(dig) -  greatest common denominator of \(a) and \(b)")
```

Assigning an initial value in

```
var dig = 0
```

is the correct solution.

Btw., the [Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is a much more effective method to
compute the greatest common divisor, see for example
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Swift.